# Why does Apache start automatically?

Tags: apache2, lighttpd

I've some issues with my webservers Apache and lighttpd on Ubuntu 9.04.

I use lighttpd only and I've stopped Apache on Ubuntu, but for some reason since few days ago, Apache starts to run and I need to stop it in order to restart lighttpd.

What could be the reason ? Cron has nothing about this. And this issue started to exist just last week.

How can I disable Apache ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always uninstall Apache with `sudo apt-get remove apache2` - though it's likely that it's been re-added to `update-rc.d` - You can remove it with `sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove` This will remove it from start up.

Comment: I'm actually not rebooting the server. It just starts without rebooting.

Comment: @Patrick - that's...odd - do you have something like `monit` installed? Furthermore un-installation of course is the most permanent solution

Comment: Maybe it's the cronjob for rotatelogs which reloads Apache after rotating the logs. Please check your Apache error logs so you can see when Apache had started.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps aux | grep apache` when it's running and see which command started it. `ls -l /etc/logrotate.d/` and check for an apache file.  It is possible as the comment by @Lekensteyn mentioned that it exists but it should be checking for an apache PID before trying to reload.